# Java multivariate non-linear optimizer library with constraints

Tags: java, optimization

I've been searching for 3 days now for a Java library that is capable of doing multivariate non-linear optimizations in java. I've come up with a few, the most notable being the Apache Commons optimizer package. Unfortunately, I can't find many examples and I'm not experienced enough to figure out how to use their optimization package without some examples. Could somebody point me to an example of how to solve a multivariate optimization problem with the Apache Commons package or point me to some documentation that can help me out?

Comment: You've been searching the official documentation for 3 days? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/optimization.html TBH I've seen worse documentations of open source projects.

Comment: Ok, so my problem is 267 dimensions. Although it is differentiable, I don't want to be stuck writing down 267 partial derivatives. So I looked at the 4 multivariable direct solvers that they had. I need something that can take in a linear constraint. on their site it says that they offer 4 solvers, two of which can't manage constraints by themselves. So I looked at the other two solvers, the Bobyqa and the CMA solvers. When it comes to the optimization method, there is no indication of what the arguments should be. In the documentation it just says OptimizationData...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(See also the answer to your recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16950115/650012)).

If you are looking for a nonlinear optimizer in Java that can handle (non)linear constraints and does not rely on derivatives, I would recommend Michael Powell's COBYLA2 algorithm. I have converted the original FORTRAN implementation of this algorithm into Java, and you can find the corresponding code on [Github](https://github.com/cureos/jcobyla) and [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/508513/Derivative-free-nonlinear-optimization-for-NET-and).

Now, 267 variables might be a challenge to COBYLA2 or for that matter any optimizer that does not rely on derivatives. Please make sure that you allow for a large number of objective function calculations to ensure that the algorithm has sufficient space to converge towards an optimum.

If you are willing to consider a gradient-based algorithm I could otherwise recommend [IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt). IPOPT is implemented in C++, but a [Java interface](http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node26.html) via JNI is part of the official distribution.

Comment: With the IPOPT algorithm, do I have to compute the gradient by hand? I'm trying to avoid having to work with this 267 variable function and leave the algorithm to do the work.

Comment: IPOPT by itself does not provide any gradient estimation or [automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation), but you might be able to find AD support for Java for example in Apache Commons Math.

Answer (score 2):

If your variable's value ranges are discrete: [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) is also a Java library that is capable of doing multivariable non-linear optimizations. It has examples up to 50000 variables (with 5000 values each).