# Apache Commons Optimization Troubles

Tags: java, optimization, multidimensional-array, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve a constrained non-linear 267 dimensional optimization problem with the java optimization library supplied by Apache Commons.

After 3 days of deciphering, this is what I have:

```
public class optimize2 {

public static void main(String []args){

    double[] point = {1.,2.};
    double[] cost = {3., 2.};
    MultivariateFunction function = new MultivariateFunction() {
            public double value(double[] point) {
                    double x = point[0];
                    double y = point[1];
                    return x * y;
            }
    };


    MultivariateOptimizer optimize = new BOBYQAOptimizer(5);
    optimize.optimize(
            new MaxEval(200),
            GoalType.MAXIMIZE,
            new InitialGuess(point),
            new ObjectiveFunction(function),
            new LinearConstraint(cost, Relationship.EQ, 30));
}
```

}

For whatever reason optimize.optimize() is throwing a null pointer error. Maybe I'm just being dumb but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Here is the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.BOBYQAOptimizer.setup(BOBYQAOptimizer.java:2401)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.BOBYQAOptimizer.doOptimize(BOBYQAOptimizer.java:236)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.BOBYQAOptimizer.doOptimize(BOBYQAOptimizer.java:49)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.BaseOptimizer.optimize(BaseOptimizer.java:143)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.BaseMultivariateOptimizer.optimize(BaseMultivariateOptimizer.java:66)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.MultivariateOptimizer.optimize(MultivariateOptimizer.java:64)
    at Test.Code.optimize2.main(optimize2.java:39)

Comment: Post the complete error message including the stacktrace.

Comment: The *BOBYQA* algorithm does not support linear or nonlinear constraints, only variable bounds. I am not 100% sure, but I don't actually think that any of the nonlinear opt algorithms in *Apache Commons Math* is capable of handling constraints other than variable bounds. Powell's *COBYLA2* algorithm does have support for arbitrary constraints. I have converted the Fortran code of the original implementation to Java, you can find it [here](https://github.com/cureos/jcobyla) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/508513/Derivative-free-nonlinear-optimization-for-NET-and).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking directly into the [BOBYQA code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/nonlinear/scalar/noderiv/BOBYQAOptimizer.java?view=markup), it actually seems like the problem is that you have not explicitly defined any variable bounds. Line 2401 (`setup` method) reads as follows:

```
boundDifference[i] = upperBound[i] - lowerBound[i];
```

In the `doOptimze` method, prior to calling `setup` the bounds are set using these methods:

```
final double[] lowerBound = getLowerBound();
final double[] upperBound = getUpperBound();
```

These methods are defined in [BaseMultivariateOptimizer](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/BaseMultivariateOptimizer.java?view=markup) like this:

```
public double[] getLowerBound() {
    return lowerBound == null ? null : lowerBound.clone();
}
```

(and analogously for `getUpperBound()`). But `lowerBound` and `upperBound` in *BaseMultivariateOptimizer*  are only set if the optimization data in the `optimize` call contains bounds information. If the bounds are not set in the call to `optimize`, you should therefore receive a `NullPointerException`.

Looking at the [BOBYQA test code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/nonlinear/scalar/noderiv/BOBYQAOptimizerTest.java?view=markup) it seems like it should be sufficient if you add the following argument to the `optimize` call:

```
SimpleBounds.unbounded(point.length)
```

Having said that, I also do not think you will be able to completely solve your problem using any of the nonlinear optimizers in *Apache Commons Math*, since as far as I can tell none of these optimizers can handle linear or nonlinear constraints. I recommend that you take a look at for example Michael Powell's *COBYLA2* algorithm instead. I have migrated the original FORTRAN code of this algorithm to Java, and you can find the code [here](https://github.com/cureos/jcobyla) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/508513/Derivative-free-nonlinear-optimization-for-NET-and).

Comment: Ok, so I was trying out Jcobyla and I'm a bit confused about the representation of the constraints. Say I wanted the constraint 500 = x[1] + x[0]. How would I represent that in the compute function.

Comment: @InspiredOne The constraints in *COBYLA2* should be formulated such that each constraint function is required to be non-negative, i.e. **C(x) >= 0**. I think that the feasible way to handle an equality constraint **C=e** is to formulate it as a squared difference with a small tolerance, **(C-e)^2 <= tol** or reformulated to fit *COBYLA2* , **tol - (C-e)^2 >= 0**.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up. I'm so excited to continue with my project. I've been stuck with optimization problems for a week. You are the best :)